# what does this C matrix code do?

Tags: c, matrix

```
int matrix[50][100], a, b, c; 
matrix[a][b] = c;
```

I really dont understand what this C code does, and I need to do that so I can "translate it" into assembler

Comment: Nothing good. Plays with undefined values.

Comment: Try it and you'll know.

Comment: If you want to translate it to assembler - pick a compiler and instruct it to print assembly instead of producing binary.

Comment: How can you know assembly but not C? No, seriously...

Comment: The behavior of code is Undefined because of garbage values in `a`, `b`. You may get a segmentation fault sometime. + if your want to inspect you code at low level you can use `gcc -S file.c` this will give you a asm code in `file.s`. Yes there is no syntax error so your code will compile successfully

Answer (score 3):

```
int matrix[50][100], a, b, c; 
matrix[a][b] = c;
```

It creates 50 arrays of 100 `int`. Then it initialize the `b`th integer of the `a`th array with the value `c`. But you shall initialize `a`, `b` and `c`. Otherwise, since they have automatic storage duration, their values will be undefined.

```
int matrix[50][100];
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
int c = 4;
matrix[a][b] = c;
```

This is how my `gcc` (4.4.4) turns the code into assembly (AT&T syntax):

```
movl    $2, -4(%ebp)                # a = 2
movl    $3, -8(%ebp)                # b = 3
movl    $4, -12(%ebp)               # c = 4
movl    -4(%ebp), %edx              # %edx = a = 2
movl    -8(%ebp), %eax              # %eax = b = 3
imull   $100, %edx, %edx            # %edx = 100 * a = 100 * 2 = 200
addl    %eax, %edx                  # %edx = %edx + b = 200 + 3 = 203
                                    # Formula: %edx = 100 * a + b
movl    -12(%ebp), %eax             # %eax = c = 4
movl    %eax, -20012(%ebp,%edx,4)   # Access to 203-th element (each of these
                                    # are 4 bytes, ie. sizeof(int) on my 
                                    # computer) and put %eax = 4 in it.
```

In C, arrays are indeed stored in [row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). That is, when writing `matrix[a][b]` in your source code, you will access to:

```
offset = row*NUMCOLS + column = a*100 + b
```

That's what the assembly code shows.

Comment: some comments in asm code will be nice :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Right. I'll update it.

Comment: to further improve you can add information that  matrix stored in col major thats why effective address calculated as `%edx = 100 * a = 100 * 2 = 200`

Comment: ok Sorry, I write wrong its row by row. that why * by 100... I forgot to + you that why I come back.and **VERY NICE ANSWER**